# Ubuntu has incorrect Gateway to 0.0.0.0 destination

Tags: ubuntu, networking, raspberry-pi

My router's IP address is 192.168.4.1 but Ubuntu has the wrong gateway (192.168.1.1) for the 0.0.0.0 destination.

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     207    0        0 veth25c3672
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b0d0fb5e0e31
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on my Raspberry Pi.

Edit:

This is the output from `ip addr`:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:94:9c:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.111/22 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 13792sec preferred_lft 13792sec
    inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fda1:a63d:515d:3:406:1189:9d9a:cb0a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1763sec preferred_lft 1763sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe94:9cf9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:94:9c:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:84:54:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.144.13/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1aae:616e:f298:1a57/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-b0d0fb5e0e31: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c2:38:d1:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-b0d0fb5e0e31
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth25c3672@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 5e:70:b9:32:6d:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.131.198/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute veth25c3672
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2171:b3e8:2409:538a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5c70:b9ff:fe32:6d76/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I also ran this command:

```
systemctl stop dhcpcd ; rm /var/lib/dhcpcd*/*lease* ; systemctl start dhcpcd
```

but the bad gateway `191.168.1.1` still shows up for `eth0`

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     207    0        0 veth25c3672
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b0d0fb5e0e31
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Your netmasks are wrong somewhere, or you have 2 subnets on the same lan or that default gateway is static. That 192.168.4.0 - 255.255.252.0 or /22 gives a range from 192.168.4.x to 192.168.7.x, but your localhost appears in the 192.168.1.0 - 255.255.255.0 or /24 range. Perhaps it is seeing another router.

Comment: I used to have this connected to another router that had the 192.168.1.1 gateway. The new router has the 192.168.4.1 gateway. I'm pretty sure that I haven't hardcoded anything.

Comment: output from `ip addr` will give a hint.

Comment: And if you are picking up a dhcp address from the router, then run the following which should reset things. `systemctl stop dhcpcd ; rm /var/lib/dhcpcd*/*lease* ; systemctl start dhcpcd`

Comment: Updated the post with the output from `ip addr` as well as after running `systemctl stop dhcpcd ; rm /var/lib/dhcpcd*/*lease* ; systemctl start dhcpcd`

Answer (score 1):

```
inet 192.168.4.111/22 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft 13792sec preferred_lft 13792sec
```

The above shows us that it is from DHCP.

while the below shows us that is is static. Most probably through NetworkManager. Delete it there.

```
inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```